# Adding a SQLite database to .NET MAUI App crashes with error: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3' or one of its dependencies:

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I'm adding a SQLite Database to a .NET MAUI application

When running the app I get an InnerException message

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3' or one of its
> dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

I added these 4 packages from Nuget

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.0.7" />
```

This is the class to create the database and CRUD operations

```
    readonly SQLiteConnection database;

    public Repository(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath); // Error occurs here
        database.CreateTable<TodoItem>();
    }

    public List<TodoItem> GetTodos()
    {
        return database.Table<TodoItem>().ToList();
    }

    public TodoItem GetTodo(Guid id)
    {
        return database.Table<TodoItem>()
                        .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public int SaveTodo(TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.ID != Guid.Empty)
        {
            return database.Update(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.Insert(item);
        }
    }

    public int DeleteTodo(TodoItem todo)
    {
        return database.Delete(todo);
    }
```

I added the database in App.xaml.cs

```
    static Repository database;

    // Create the database connection as a singleton.
    public static Repository Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (database == null)
            {
                database = new Repository(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "todo.db"));
            }
            return database;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
This error occurs when running the app as a Windows Machine App

Comment: If you are curious, looks like that problem [was reported two years ago](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19396) and last work on it was from july 2021.

Comment: Have you added the database in App.xaml.cs

Comment: Look here https://vladislavantonyuk.azurewebsites.net/articles/Adding-SQLite-to-the-.NET-MAUI-application  under Then create repository class:

Comment: @BasH That's exactly the article I used to add the database